# I am trying to find out how to compare two dates in a visual basic database

Tags: vb.net

I currently have a visual basic database made in Microsoft access. In this database, I allow the user to enter a date in a text box and this date gets saved to the database. I want to compare the dates "on the database!".  The hard part is that the dates are entered in the same text box but saved on different rows. I need to compare the different dates in the rows of the database.

Comment: Create a query with two subqueries, one for each date.

Comment: `The hard part is...` No, the hard part is figuring out what the real problem is.  If the dates are related to a logical object, they should probably be in the same row.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow, This is just a message I send to new members to help things along a bit. The learning curve for a new user isn't steep as such, but finding out how to use stack isn't always obvious. Please do take a few minutes and have a look here [ask] and it's also important to look here .. [mcve].. Also, if an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Fetch data from the database and use FOR EACH loop to compare. A sample code is as follows:

```
Dim con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=Test.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
con.Open()

Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT date_col FROM my_table", con)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
Dim dt As DataTable = reader.GetSchemaTable()

For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
    If row.Item("date_col") = **your_criteria** Then
        **your_other_statements**
    End if
Next row
con.Close()
```

Hope this will help